# HTML sortable table with indicator of row increasing or decreasing

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout-2.0

I'd like to have an HTML table that is dynamically populated at runtime with rows ordered by a given attribute.  As the attribute is updated dynamically it may move the row up or down in the HTML table.  I'd like to indicate a row moving up or down in the with something as simple as a red (down) or green (up) color, arrow icon ...  is there a jquery plugging or something that already does this?
My stack is jquery, knockout, and google charts.

Comment: https://datatables.net/ Is a pretty good plugin for making good tables with jQuery, though whether or not it supports the exact feature you described I unfortunately don't know.

Comment: stack overflow is not meant to work like you are trying to use it.  submit code questions not requests.  if you dont have code to paste in your question you are probably doing it wrong.  however, i understand your problem and encourage you to check out a free product called bootgrid... search google for it.